# "Être reconnu(e) dans"

Tags: expressions, usage, synonymes, registre

> Personnellement, je me suis reconnu dans ces valeurs qui sont partagées au sein de ce département.

Qu'est-ce que cette phrase signifie ? Comment peut-on la reformuler en gardant toujours le même registre ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cette phrase signifie que le département (d'une entreprise) partage les même valeurs que le locuteur. par exemple: Partage, convivialité, bonne ambiance etc..

Nous pourrions la reformuler de la manière suivante:

> Personnellement, je me suis reconnu dans **l**es valeurs qui sont
>   partagées au sein de ce département.

Ou encore:

> Personnellement, je partage les même valeurs que mes collègues au seins de ce département.

Answer (score 1):

"Se reconnaître" laisse penser à un miroir. Je vois une image dans le miroir et je me reconnais moi-même dans cette image (ce que l'on fait parfois avec des animaux pour essayer de déterminer s'ils ont conscience d'eux-mêmes) ou, autrement dit, je m'identifie à cette image.

Dans ce cadre, le "département" peut également projeter une image à laquelle je m'identifie parce qu'elle est proche de ce que je suis.